# A triangle has sides $a$, $b$, $c$ and medians $m_a$, $m_b$, $m_c$. Show $(ab+bc+ca)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})\geq 2\sqrt{3}(m_a+m_b+m_c)$

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities, sum-of-squares-method

> Let $\triangle ABC$ have sides $BC=a$, $CA=b$, and $AB=c$. Let $m_a$, $m_b$, $m_c$ be the medians to $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$, respectively. Prove that
>   $$(ab+bc+ca)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\geq 2\sqrt{3}(m_a+m_b+m_c)$$

My trying: $$\Leftrightarrow (ab+bc+ca)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)\geq 3\sqrt{3}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
Because: $$m_a+m_b+m_c\leq \sqrt{3(m_{a}^{2}+m_{b}^{2}+m_{c}^{2})}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \left(p^2+4Rr+r^2\right)\left(\frac{4R+r}{pr}
\right)\geq 3\sqrt{3}\sqrt{2p^2-8Rr-2r^2}$$
I square it, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The hint:

Draw the $\Delta ABC$ with medians $m_b=BD$ and $CE=m_a$.

Thus, by the Ptolemy's theorem for the equilateral $BCDE$ we obtain:
$$BE\cdot DC+BC\cdot ED\geq BD\cdot CE$$ or
$$\frac{bc}{4}+\frac{a^2}{2}\geq m_am_b.$$
Hence, $$\sum_{cyc}m_a=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(m_a^2+2m_bm_c\right)}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(m_a^2+2\left(\frac{bc}{4}+\frac{a^2}{2}\right)\right)}=$$ 
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{4}(2b^2+2c^2-a^2)+2\left(\frac{bc}{4}+\frac{a^2}{2}\right)\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(7a^2+2ab)}.$$ 
It est, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{(ab+ac+bc)^4}{3a^2b^2c^2}\geq\sum_{cyc}(7a^2+2ab).$$
Now, let $a=y+z$, $b=x+z$ and $c=x+y$.

Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives and we need to prove that
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}(x^2+3xy)\right)^4\geq3\prod_{cyc}(x+y)^2\sum_{cyc}(14x^2+14y^2+2x^2+6xy)$$ or 
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}(x^2+3xy)\right)^4\geq12\prod_{cyc}(x+y)^2\sum_{cyc}(4x^2+5xy)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^8+12x^7y+12x^7z+10x^6y^2+10x^6z^2-12x^5y^3-12x^5z^3-21x^4y^4)+$$
$$+24xyz\sum_{cyc}(x^5-x^3y^2-x^3z^2+x^2y^2z)\geq0.$$
Now, $$\sum_{cyc}(x^8+12x^7y+12x^7z+10x^6y^2+10x^6z^2-12x^5y^3-12x^5z^3-21x^4y^4)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x^8+y^8+24x^7y+24xy^7+20x^6y^2+20x^2y^6-24x^5y^3-24x^3y^5-42x^4y^4)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x^2-y^2)^2(x^4+24x^3y+22x^2y^2+24xy^3+y^4)\geq0$$ and let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus,
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^5-x^3y^2-x^3z^2+x^2y^2z)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x^5-x^3y^2-x^2y^3+y^5-(x^3z^2-x^2yz^2-y^2xz^2+y^3z^2))=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2((x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2)-(x+y)z^2)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2-z^2)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}\left((x-z)^2(x+z)(x^2-y^2)+(y-z)^2(y+z)(y^2-x^2)\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}\left((y-z)^2(x+z)(x^2-y^2)+(y-z)^2(y+z)(y^2-x^2)\right)=\frac{1}{2}(y-z)^2(x-y)^2(x+y)\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Please help me prove the last. Do you have another solution?

Comment: @Winter In My Heart Also, it's true after the Ravi's substitution and full expanding.  It's very ugly, but it's proof.

Comment: No problem, show it please

Comment: @Winter In My Heart  I fixed a typo in my proof. See now.